# XSLT - copy nodes to new location and remove original

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I have a xml like follows,

```
<session>
    <foot>
        <p type="note">
            <link ref="http://www.facebook.com">
                <c type="Hyperlink">www.faceook.com</c>
            </link>
        </p>
    </foot>
    <foot>
        <p type="note">
            <link ref="http://www.google.com">
                <c type="Hyperlink">www.google.com</c>
            </link>
        </p>
    </foot>
    <middle>

    </middle>
    <middle>

    </middle>
</session>
```

My requirements are,

1) add dynamic id to `<p>` node which has attribute value of `type="note"`

2) and new node named `<newNode>` inside `<p>` node which has attribute value of `type="note"`

3) add dynamic id to newly created `<newNode>`

4) add a `<Finish>` node just before end of `<session>` nodes which has at least node `<foot>` node

5) copy all `<foot>` nodes between  node and  node

6) get rid of original `<foot>` nodes

so the output should be,

```
<session>

    <middle>

    </middle>
    <middle>

    </middle>
    <Finish type="Endnotes">End</Finish><foot>
        <p id="id-1" type="note">
            <link ref="http://www.facebook.com">
                <c type="Hyperlink">www.faceook.com</c>
            </link>
            <newNode refType="middle" ref="id-1"/></p>
    </foot><foot>
        <p id="id-2" type="note">
            <link ref="http://www.google.com">
                <c type="Hyperlink">www.google.com</c>
            </link>
            <newNode refType="middle" ref="id-2"/></p>
    </foot>
   </session>
```

To achieve this task I have written following xsl,

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- create dynamic id in <p> node -->
    <xsl:template match="p[@type='note']">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">
                <xsl:value-of select="'id-'"/> 
                <xsl:number count="p[@type='note']" level="any"/>
            </xsl:attribute>

            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />

            <!-- add new node named <newNode> in <foot> -->
            <newNode refType="middle">
                <xsl:attribute name="ref">
                    <xsl:value-of select="'id-'"/>
                    <xsl:number count="p[@type='note']" level="any"></xsl:number>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </newNode>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- select session which has <foot> nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="session[.//foot]">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
            <!-- create <Finish> node just before </session> -->
            <Finish type="Endnotes">End</Finish>
            <!-- copy <foot> node between <Finish> and </session> -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="current()//foot"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- get rid of original <foot> nodes-->
    <xsl:template match="session//foot"/>
```

Only problem I have is when I write `<xsl:template match="session//foot"/>` to get rid of original `<foot>` nodes it removes every `<foot>` which copy to new place as well.

can anyone suggest a method that keep the `<foot>` node which copy to new location and remove original `<foot>` nodes.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Only problem I have is when I write `<xsl:template
>   match="session//foot"/>` to get rid of original `<foot>` nodes it removes
>   every `<foot>` which copy to new place as well.

That's because you're using:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current()//foot"/>
```

to place the nodes. This applies again the empty template that you have written, so there is nothing being output. You should be using either:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="current()//foot"/>
```

or:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="current()//foot" mode="move"/>
```

and write another template matching `foot` with the same mode to handle it.

A third option is to remove the empty template matching `foot` altogether, and be more selective when applying templates instead. Instead of:

```
<!-- select session which has <foot> nodes -->
<xsl:template match="session[.//foot]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() "/>
```

do:

```
<!-- select session which has <foot> nodes -->
<xsl:template match="session[.//foot]">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node() except foot"/>
```

This assumes that `foot` is always a child of `session`, as shown in your example. Your stylesheet obviously expects it elsewhere too (otherwise why use the `//` in `.//foot`) so you might have to add a similar exception in more places.

Comment: your first solution (copy-of) did not work well because when added copy of, dynamic ids were not copied to new location. But second solution (add mode) works pretty well. Thanks for the answer. :)